# VBA макросы Excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub replace()
For j = 1 To 5
  For i = 1 To 5
    If Sheets("Лист 1").Cells(j, 1) <> Sheets("Лист 2").Cells(i, 1) Then
      Sheets("Лист 1").Activate
      Sheets("Лист 1").Cells(j, 1).Select
      Selection.Copy
      Sheets("Лист 2").Activate
      Sheets("Лист 2").Cells(i, 1).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
  Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Нужно чтобы по нажатию макрос проверял значение из Лист 1 и если оно не такое же как в Лист 2, макрос копировал значение из лист 1 в лист 2, в соответствующую ячейку, которая задаётся циклом.
В моем случае макрос заменяет все ячейки Листа 2 одинаковой цифрой пока не дойдет до конца. В конце диапазона он меняет цифру на следующуб из листа 1.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если диапазон Листа2 должен соответствовать диапазону Листа1 - зачем цикл? Копировать-Вставить целым диапазоном: *Worksheets("Лист 2").Range("A1:A5").Value = Worksheets("Лист 1").Range("A1:A5").Value*

Comment: Ну да, логично, спасибо

Comment: Он заменяет с одной цифрой потому что `Sheets("Лист 1").Cells(j, 1) <> Sheets("Лист 2").Cells(i, 1)`  в одном листе **i** а в другом **j**